# load external image with jquery

Tags: jquery

I try this code to change a img image and it work in localhost but is dosent work on my host .
these are the way that i treid:

```
$("#btnChangImg").click(function () {
             $("#Div").html('<img id="img" alt="" src="/Test/2.jpg" />');
});
```

And this a another way that i treid:

```
$("#btnChangImg").click(function () {
             $("#img").attr("src", "/Test/2.jpg");
});
```

src of the #img is "/Test/1.jpg" now.and it should be change to "/Test/1.jpg"

and this is my HTML:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="Div">
    <img id="img" alt="" src="/Test/1.jpg" />
</div>
<input id="btnChangImg" type="button" value="button" />
</form>
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML

Comment: Please post your HTML, and explain what doesn't work. Is there a JS error, a 404 or does nothing happen at all?

Comment: tnkx for your replaye . i edit my question

Comment: what about $("#btnChangImg").click(function () {
$('#img').attr('src','/Test/2.jpg');});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET or something like that it might be possible that your id is changed when the page is rendered because your code is correct

```
$("#btnChangImg").click(function () {
             $("#img").attr("src", "/Test/2.jpg");
});
```

Look at the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/KBWk8/

Comment: unless you use asp.net 4 and have clientidmode to static

Comment: @JPHellemons i'm no expert of asp.net, if it was JSF the id would be easy to determine! :)

Comment: No problem, still good to point out that he might be needing $('<%=imgName.ClientId()%>') http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$("div").click(function(){
    $("img").attr("src", "secondImage.jpg")            
})
```

Here is a jsFiddle I made: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjQ7t/1/